# I want to authenticate Google workspace users with username and password through an API call

Tags: google-oauth

I have a use case where I want to authenticate Google workspace users with username and password. Is there a way to do it?

I can do it in Azure AD with OAUTH2.0 ROPC flow but unable to find any documentation in Google to do that.

I tried exploring the documentation but couldn't find any, I initially thought APIGEE might be able to call internal Google identity server to authenticate user, but it seems like I was wrong.

Comment: And how do you want to do this exactly?  Sharing username and password is never a smart thing.

Comment: I am trying to integrate Google IDP into an app that supports radius authentication. I want users to get into the network by entering the google's username and password.